# What is the proper nomenclature for CH₂O₂?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Can you tell me what's the nomenclature of $\ce{C H_2 O_2}$?

What is its IUPAC name?

Comment: [This](http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure) can be a useful site for such queries if you know the structure of the compound or atleast one name, for example to answer your query click [this](http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/C%28O%29%3DO/names)

Answer (score 2):

The compound you provided can be written more clearly as $\ce{HCOOH}$

IUPAC name : Formic acid

Systematic name :Methanoic Acid

Other names:
Aminic acid, Formylic acid, Hydrogen carboxylic acid, Hydroxymethanone, Hydroxy(oxo)methane, Metacarbonoic acid, Oxocarbinic acid, Oxomethanol

Comment: Well it could also be dioxirane. Maybe Bharat Khanna could precise his question and the context in which he came up to it.

Comment: It could also be dihydroxymethylidene.